# Plumbing/water main shut off

Tags: plumbing, well

I live in a mobile home community with its own well system and it has had nothing but problems resulting in the main water being shut off for repairs extremely frequently without notice. I can always tell because it sounds awful when using anything that runs water after it’s been shut off, sounding like it’s going to explode with the gushes of air and water. I am concerned that this is going to damage my pipes, washer, dishwasher and toilet. Should I be concerned or is that normal?  Also because our pipes are apparently some sort of plastic that’s been discontinued, no company will insure us so if a pipe bursts I have no idea what we’ll do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that can cause damage but usually from debris being kicked up by those pockets of air in the lines.

You should open a tap in a bathtub or utility sink and let the water flow until the air is purged.

An outside hose bib is also a good choice for this.

As far as insurance, I am not sure anyone here can help on that front.